# RAD studio takes very long time to open

Tags: windows, delphi, ide, rad

I was using RAD 10.1 (Berlin) with no problem until now... Last month I applied Windows Creator Update and was occupied by other businesses... Now, each time I start the IDE, the loading progresses quickly up to "All design time packages loaded". At this time RAD studio sits on its splash window and consumes ~25% CPU. It takes at least 10 minutes before the IDE appears...

I've installed RAD 10.2 (Tokyo) and all provided patches, hoping for a fix... But the problem remains the same.

I can't go back to previous version of Windows 10 (more than 10 days after install).

I've already searched for an answer and Matthias E suggested that it was linked to https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17972.
But, in my case, the (very) long period stands only for IDE loading even when there is no project to (auto)load. I'm not talking about the time-period to load the project or to start project execution or even to start the application execution. Once the IDE has been loaded (after ~20'), everything (editing, compilation, building, debugging, execution) is working quickly...
I have become accustomed to never close the IDE once opened but this is particularly disturbing.

Could you help me ?

**--- Edited ---**

For those who cannot access the link above, here is the content :

**Details**

```
Type:    Bug Bug
Status:    Open Open
Priority:    Major Major
Resolution:    Unresolved
Affects Version/s:    10.2 Tokyo, 10.1 Berlin Update 2
Fix Version/s:    None
Component/s:    Debugger, IDE (Development Environment), Libraries/Frameworks
Labels:    None
Platform:    Windows 10 
Language Version:    English
Edition:    Professional
InternalID:    RS-83785
InternalStatus:    Open
```

**Description**

The debugger goes haywire for everyone in our organization with Creators and Tokyo/Berlin. Reverting to Windows Anniversary brings back the sanity.
Debugger problems with Tokyo/Berlin and Creators:
    App takes a long time to load with modules loading and unloading and re-loading many times
    IDE freezes
    Memory consumption of bds.exe explodes, sometimes (> 3GB)
I will attached before and after screenshots showing how modules load and unload and re-load with Windows 10 Creators.
I presume these problems have the same root cause(s) than those in https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=884382*

**--- ---**

Comment: You can't follow the link without creating an EDN account. *<rant>I never understood policies that forces you to have an account to merely view issues </rant>.*

Comment: Read this: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2017-june-delphi-packages-creators-update.html. The IDE relies on a lot of packages too, so it may be affected too (although on my system, I have no problems -- I am not sure, but I guess it is because my install is not in a subdirectory of `C:\Program Files (x86)`, but in a directory of its own).

Comment: @ Lieven Keersmaekers, I've edited my question and included the content of the link. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ Rudy Velthuis, thank you for your answer. My install is on a distinct disk partition (H:\Program Files (x86)). Would you suggest to install elsewhere ?

Comment: I don't see why the location of the install would matter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is the only difference I have with the default install. For me, things work normally, even on Win10 Creators update.

Comment: @Mouscap: then it shouldn't make a difference. But is that on the main disk, or an external one, or what?

Comment: @rudy No probs for me installed in default location.

Comment: @David: OK, then that was not it. <g>

Comment: @Mouscap - if you are certain it's not related to what's described in the link Rudy provided, I'd download `procmon` from Microsoft Sysinternals, let it run for a few minutes while starting your ide and analyze it's logging *(or have it analyzed here if you can share it)*.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers - I'm not certain it's not related to the above link... I've downloaded procmon but, even after having closed every running application, it still generates a lot of information. What should be the best way to filter out unusable or useless data ?

Comment: @Rudy & David - I've reinstalled RAD on the default location after having removed the first one (located on another partition of the main disk). No change... I've installed on another PC with Creator Update installed and ... it works. But this is not the best solution for me.

Comment: @Mouscap - Easiest is `CTRL-T`, select RAD studio and filter on those (+ childrens) events.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers - Thank you very much for this invaluable information ! By using procmon, I've seen that RAD studio was trying hardly to access an enormous (128 GB) zip backup file (see : http://qed-electronic.com/Download/170808-ProcMonTrace.jpg ). Why ? I don't know : none of my projects or files are located in this zip file. I've simply moved the backup file... Solved ! RAD is now starting in 12". Thank you to all of you.

Comment: @Mouscap - Good to hear you've got it solved. The Windows Creator Update most likely doesn't have anything to do with it then ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Lieven Keersmaekers's suggestion to use procmon, I was able to find the cause of the problem. RAD studio was heavily trying to access an enormous (128 GB) zip backup file (see : qed-electronic.com/Download/170808-ProcMonTrace.jpg ). I've simply moved the backup file to another location and RAD studio now starts as before. I have no idea why RAD wanted so much to access this file : none of my project files were located in this zip. The Windows Creator Update was apparently not guilty...

Comment: I used the procmon tip and discovered the same issue.  It appears that RAD Studio scans all *.ZIP files in the Desktop folder.  I moved all zips off of my Desktop folder and RAD studio startup time changed from 5 minutes to about 10 seconds.  This impacts at least Delphi XE and Delphi 10.2.  Very strange.  Not sure why the IDE needs to scan random zip files.

Answer (score 0):

**bds.exe  must be launch with only one CPU  !**

CPU Affinity CPU=0

Thx to Javorszky

https://community.embarcadero.com/forum/installation-issues/1408-running-from-ide-freezes-windows-10#4173

To run quickly without entring  TaskManager and change Setting CPUAffinity,

just create a batch file on the desktop:

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\"
start /affinity 1 bds.exe

Why ?

"The reason for this is that most applications you run these days have been designed with multi-core processors in mind and will work with the operating system to distribute their operations as evenly as possible across all the available cores. "

see :   https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/